# How to create a blank RTF file in AppleScript inside current folder?

Tags: applescript

In regards to this question: [How to create a blank RTF file in AppleScript?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270689/how-to-create-a-blank-rtf-file-in-applescript/290283#290283)

Can you modify the code in a way it would save the file to the current location of the app? as in instead of saving it to Desktop, it would save it to wherever the .app is located. That way I could add the .app to the Finder-Toolbar and be able to click it from any folder and create that blank rtf file inside the current folder whatever it may be.

if not possible, then maybe force it to ask for saving-location just like it asks for name.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the *code* in that linked answer, *as is*, and modify it to do exactly what it's presently doing with the exception of creating the RTF file at the location the Finder window is set to, via the .app added to the Toolbar in Finder, then change the following line of *code*:

Change:

```
set theCustomRichTextFilePathname to ((path to desktop) & customFilename & ".rtf") as string
```

To:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theCustomRichTextFilePathname to ((folder of the front window as string) & customFilename & ".rtf") as string
end tell
```

Then save it as an AppleScript .app, not .scpt, and drag and drop it onto the Toolbar in Finder.

While that technically answers your question, nonetheless there's probably other *code* that may/will need to be modified, but that gets you started.